# Is there a way to load Maven Surefire Plugin exclusions list from a file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

In the Surefire plugin, you have have an [exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) list of files (or regex) like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

I want to add a bunch of files to my exclusions list that don't match a regex. This list is about 200 files (an eccentric collection). I'd like to add those files from a file external to my Maven `pom.xml`.

I think there is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven) to do this using the maven properties plugin. I can't see how that would load a [variable into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841363/can-i-pass-a-list-from-a-maven-property-into-a-plugins-configuration) though.

Is there a way to load the exclusions list from a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Surefire plugin provides exactly the configuration element for this, called [`excludesFile`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludesFile):

> A file containing exclude patterns. Blank lines, or lines starting with `#` are ignored. If `excludes` are also specified, these patterns are appended. Example with path, simple and regex excludes:
>   `*/test/*`
>   `**/DontRunTest.*`
>   `%regex[.*Test.*|.*Not.*]`

It was introduced in version 2.19  of the plugin as part of [SUREFIRE-1065](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1065) and [SUREFIRE-1134](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1134). As such, you could directly have a file called `surefireExcludes.txt` at the base directory of your project, containing

```
**/TestCircle.java
**/TestSquare.java
# **/TestRectangle.java A commented-out pattern
```

and then configure the plugin with:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludesFile>surefireExcludes.txt</excludesFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

All of the tests will be run, except for those matching the patterns specified in the file. The patterns can be even commented-out if they start with `#`. This could also be passed directly on the command-line with the `surefire.excludesFile` user property, i.e.:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.excludesFile=surefireExcludes.txt
```

The parameter [`includesFile`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includesFile) also exists for the opposite requirement.