# Can jacoco maven plugin read exclusions from a file?

Tags: java, maven, junit, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

You can run [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) tests with the [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) agent to produce wonderful coverage reports. (It produces an opaque `*.exec` file during the running of the unit tests).

Now surefire [has a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644760/is-there-a-way-to-load-maven-surefire-plugin-exclusions-list-from-a-file) to load exclusions from a file.

Maven can [read a properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven) list. It might be able to read a [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841363/can-i-pass-a-list-from-a-maven-property-into-a-plugins-configuration) into a list.

My question is: **Can jacoco maven plugin read exclusions from a file?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the list of files which you want to exclude in a separate file and then read that file?

Comment: Curious to know why don't you exclude using 
`<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*tmp.*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>`

Comment: Correct @AST - I have about 300 files I'd like to exclude and I don't want it bogging down my Pom.xml

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work, I tried reproducing it on my machine but it does not exclude.
In log it showed :

`surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:/home/ankit/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/ankit/workspace/DTX/plugins/maven/dt-packaging/target/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec,excludes=./pom.txt`

Comment: What are the reason to exclude 300 files? Do you want to exclude them from instrumentation or/and from report? Are they located in same package?

@ASR wildcards (`*`) are working just fine

Comment: They're not in the one package. They're deprecated code - Jacoco results feed into a build breaker for coverage goals for the team.

Comment: I am seeking the same information, and I think hawkeye's use case is valid.  The list may be long; the same list may be an input to more than one plugin; the list could be generated from other information such as a bug database.  The older Ant build tool supports "excludesfile" (which does exactly what Hawkeye is asking) just about every place it supports "excludes".  Gradle has a mechanism for this.  It would be nice if Maven had a similar feature.

Answer (score 1):

According to [jacoco-maven-plugin documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) there is no way to specify exclusions via file.